# Issue with Django template 'ifequal'

Tags: django

The Below code:

```
{% ifequal username AnonymousUser %}
    <p>Welcome</p>
{% else %} 
    <p> Welcome {{ username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>     
{% endifequal %}
```

Shows This:

```
Welcome AnonymousUser. Thanks for logging in.
```

What the? I'm more than a little miffed. I'm pretty sure i don't need to supply extra code for you to understand my problem.

I dont think it's an ifequal problem. I have a pretty good handle on that.

Username comes from:

```
username = request.user
```

Does this mean username at this point in the code is not a string. Do i have to convert it to a string.

Comment: Are you asking a Django question or about writing your StackOverflow question?

Comment: Next time please choose a more appropriate title for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare to a string. Use this:

```
{% ifequal smart_str(username).strip() "AnonymousUser" %}
```

Here's the [Django documentation on checking equality with `ifequal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal).

Ensure your variable is a string, and one that's trimmed of leading and trailing whitespaces as well.

Comment: neither "AnonymousUser" or 'AnonymousUser' makes any difference

Comment: @JT likely it's because it's not a string variable. Try converting it to a string using `str(username)`. Consider using `strip()` as well for good measure.

Comment: yeah, it wasnt a string. Now i know. cheers

Comment: does this answer really work?

Comment: it didn't work for me - afaik, function calls like that don't work in templates. but hey, I'm new to Django, so perhaps I'm completely missing something.