# Can variables with lookups be used in Django {% ifequal %} expressions?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Here's my code:

```
[{{thing.syncedthing_set.all.0.state}}]
{% ifequal thing.syncedthing_set.all.0.state "InProgress" %}
    It worked
{% endifequal %}
```

The result:

```
[InProgress]
```

In other words, the variable lookup works, but isn't passing the 'ifequal' test. I can't think of any reason this wouldn't work other than variable lookups not being supported.

There's a mailing list message from 2007 saying they weren't supported back then: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/oU1im3UTcLc - is this still the case?

If so, any good workarounds? It's not easy in this case to modify the Python code that calls the template.

If they ought to work - any other possible causes?

There's [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509435/issue-with-django-template-ifequal) but the answer doesn't work for me. I'm using Django 1.3.

EDIT

Ok, so the 'state' has type class. Looking up the definition, state refers to a class which eventually subclasses models.Field:

```
class FSMField(models.Field):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    states = {}
    """ Contains { 'Statename': StateClass, ... }"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 50)
        super(FSMField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, State):
            return value
        return self.__class__.states.get(str(value))()

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'CharField'
```

Given that - I'm actually not sure how to get a real string value in the templating system. Forgive my newbishness.

EDIT2
Actually, the relevant bit is probably the 'State' class itself:

```
class State(object):
    """ A simple finite statement machine abstract class, with on_entry and on_exit events."""
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.__class__.__name__)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: What's the type of `thing.syncedthing_set.all.0.state`? Can you show it in Django shell?

Comment: Btw - the answer to my original question is "yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between an object's string representation, and what it actually is. It seems likely that your `state` property returns an object whose unicode representation is `InProgress`, but that doesn't make it actually equal to `"InProgress"`. This would be true for example if `state` is a ForeignKey to another model - in which case you could just add another level to the lookup to get to the actual field that returns that status.

**Edit after update** I think you've coded yourself into a corner, unfortunately. Since there's no actual instance attribute that contains the state as a string, there's no way to get it via string comparison.

A couple of possibilities spring to mind. One is to pass all possible `State` subclasses to the template context (perhaps via a context processor), after which you'll be able to compare your `state` with the actual objects. This is pretty horrible.

An alternative would be to add a function, either on the `State` class or possibly on the model, which gets the state as a string. This could be as simple as the existing `__unicode__` method (you can't actually use that, because the template language forbids accessing attributes that begin with underscores). Then you can do `ifequal foo.bar.0.state.as_string "InProgress"` or whatever, and that will call the `as_string()` method and your comparison will succeed.

Comment: Yep. So, see my updated question - the class is a subclass of field, so it should behave like a CharField, right? In which case, how do I get that string value in the templating system?

Comment: oh, brilliant. That works perfectly. [To be clear - I can modify the state classes. I can't (easily) modify the place where the template gets called.]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use IF:

```
{% if thing.syncedthing_set.all.0.state == "InProgress" %}
```

Comment: same result. Turns out out the value was actually a class - thanks @okm.